# How does this joint distribution imply the following Markov chain?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, markov-chains

I've the following joint distribution:

$p(x1, x2, y1, y2) = p(x1, x2)p(y1|x1)p(y2|x2)$

And I'm told that it implies the following Markov chain:

$Y1 → X1 → X2 → Y2$

I cant' see the equality between the two. Clearly, if the given markov chain is correct then joint distribution can be written as follows:

$p(x1, x2, y1, y2) = p(y1)p(x1|y1)p(x2|x1)p(y2|x2)$

So how are those 2 joint distributions equal ?

Comment: Can you show that, in your notations, $p(x_1,x_2)p(y_1|x_1)=p(y_1)p(x_1|y_1)p(x_2|x_1)$? To begin with, $p(x_1,x_2)p(y_1|x_1)=p(x_1,x_2)p(x_1,y_1)/p(x_1)$, right? Thus...

Comment: Got it. Thanks.